# How to extend ServiceStack UserAuth using RefIdStr and RavenDB

Tags: c#, .net, nosql, servicestack, ravendb

I am attempting to create a CustomAuthUserSession along with associating my own User document with the UserAuth object using the RefIdStr property.

In the OnAuthenticated method of my CustomUserAuthSession I am doing the following

1. getting the userAuth object by the UserAuthId on the session
2. creating an instance of IDocumentSession for Raven
3. creating a new instance of User and calling Store on my document session
4. updating the RefIdStr on userAuth
5. calling SaveUserAuth on my userauth repo

here is the method

```
public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);

        var documentSession = authService.TryResolve<IDocumentSession>();

        //get userAuth from raven
        //var userAuth = documentSession.Load<UserAuth>(session.UserAuthId); //should this work?
        var userAuthRepo = authService.ResolveService<IUserAuthRepository>();
        var userAuth = userAuthRepo.GetUserAuth(session.UserAuthId);

        if (userAuth.RefIdStr == null)
        {
            //need to create new User and save to Raven
            var newUser = new User()
            {
                UserName = session.UserName,
                Email = session.Email,
                //Other properties...
            };

            documentSession.Store(newUser);

            this.UserID = newUser.Id; //UserId property on custom session

            userAuth.RefIdStr = newUser.Id;

            userAuthRepo.SaveUserAuth(userAuth); //getting error here...
        }
        else
        {
            //get User from raven
            var user = documentSession.Load<User>(userAuth.RefIdStr);

            this.UserID = user.Id;
        }
    }
```

When I get to the SaveUserAuth method, I am getting the following error...

`Attempted to associate a different object with id 'UserAuths/12345'.`

Here is how I am setting up my document store and IOC...

```
//Set up RavenDB
        var ravenStore = new DocumentStore()
        {
            ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB"
        }.Initialize();

        IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(RavenUserAuthRepository).Assembly, ravenStore);

        container.Register(ravenStore);
        container.Register(c => c.Resolve<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession()).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
```

and how I configure my auth repo....

```
//register auth repository
        container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(p => new RavenUserAuthRepository(p.Resolve<IDocumentStore>(), p.Resolve<IDocumentSession>()));

        var authRepo = (RavenUserAuthRepository)container.Resolve<IUserAuthRepository>();
```

Any ideas why this error would occur?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify...my intention is for this to work in a similar fashion as the socialbootstrapapi project.

**EDIT 2**

Per the comments below, I have changed the Funq registration of IUserAuthRepository to:

```
container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(p => new RavenUserAuthRepository(p.Resolve<IDocumentStore>(), p.Resolve<IDocumentSession>())).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
```

But I am still getting the same error...

Comment: Any ideas? Maybe @mythz will chime in show me what I've screwed up :/

Comment: This sounds like a DocumentSession issue to me to me.  Instead of resolving the DocumentSession out of the IOC, what happens if you resolve the DocumentStore and create a new session for your work?

Comment: I believe this is definitely a document session issue as the Raven AuthRepository is creating new sessions for each call(not injected by the IOC- created from doc store). I would like to only create one document session per request. This is where I'm stuck. Not sure what the proper way is to access and update the UserAuth object. I assumed I should be using the IAuthRepository but it's causing this doc session issue.

Comment: I'm throwing a shot in the dark here, but I think your IUserAuthRepository is registered as a singleton, so it could be reusing that same document session.

Comment: Should it be registered some other way? Tried to copy the auth config from the sample projects

Comment: Yeah, the samples you're looking at are probably using a repository that constructs with an IDbConnectionFactory.  That's ok to register as a singleton because it creates new connections.  RavenUserAuthRepository does not.  It uses the IDocumentSession that you pass in.  So even though you have an IDocumentSession being created in RequestScope, the RavenUserAuthRepository has been created as a singleton and is hanging onto that initial document session used to construct it.

Comment: I went ahead and tried changing the IUserAuthRepository Funq registration to be reused within the request and, unfortunately, I am getting the same error

Comment: Well...I just updated my version of SS and everything works...Not sure what was fixed in the last week or so but everything is cool now

Comment: It's important to make sure that your IDocumentSession is being disposed when you're done with it.  Many IOC's will do that for you automatically, but I'm not sure if Funq does or not.  Something to look into.

Answer (score 1):

It seems updating to the latest version of SS has fixed the issue. Not sure what changes fixed the issue but everything works as expected.